# Mysterious Error and Text In Latex Document

Tags: errors, miktex

When running Latex Document, multiple errors are coming given below.

[image]

And at the first page of PDF document mysterious and miscellaneous text are coming given below.

[image]

Comment: check for updates in the miktex console as user *and* as admin. Update the package database (menu tasks, also user and admin mode)

Comment: It is not a mystery: you are trying to execute the macro `\ifluatex` in your document, but the definition of this macro (what the hell it does) is not in any of the loaded packages, nor the document class, nor your preamble. The mystery is why this is happening, but probably you have not loaded a packages as `iftex`, for some reason. See https://www.ctan.org/topic/env-query